# Input/output error using Mac Disk Utility?

Tags: mac, dvd, disk-utility

I began trying to backup my dvd collection to an external hard drive.  I do this my making disk images(.iso) from the dvds.  To do this I use disk utility > new image > save as dvd/cd master.  Started with some Battlestar Galactica.  First 6 disks of season 1 went fine.  Next 3 disks of season 2 went fine.  First disk of season 2.5 I get an input/output error about 75% through the process.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with your disk.  If you have access to a spin doctor I would suggest that.

Since your trying to get it as an iso, MacTheRipper and Handbrake will not do this.  You could try http://www.xilisoft.com/dvd-copy-mac.html .

You could also dd from the comand line.  But this may be what disk utility already uses to create cd/dvd master copies.  Just google this for syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with the drive, or (more likely) a problem with the DVD. Perhaps there's a scratch on it, or maybe just a smudge. It's tough to say.

If you copy the files directly, you can still play it with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Also Disk Utility is not your only choice for backing up DVDs. I will point to [MactheRipper](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14414) or [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for other options.